# Fluent module name change

Tags: typelite

The name can be changed like shown in the tutorial:

```
TypeScript.Definitions()
    .ForLoadedAssemblies()
    .WithFormatter((type, f) => "I" + ((TypeLite.TsModels.TsClass)type).Name)
```

How can the module name be changed using fluent formatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it isn't possible to globally change the module name using fluent configuration.

However you can change the module name on per class basis:

```
TypeScript.Definitions().For<MyClass>().ToModule("ModuleName")
```

Comment: this is actually ok, it would be nice to change that globally but this  does it too.

Answer (score 6):

As of TypeLite version 1.4.0 the following works fine to change module name:

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
    .WithModuleNameFormatter((module) => "my.module.name");#>
```

Or you can also play with what's already set as module name to have more control like this:

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
    .WithModuleNameFormatter((module) => "I" + ((TypeLite.TsModels.TsModule)module).Name);#>
```

Comment: Works globally! I think this answer should be selected as correct one. Thank you.

Comment: @mentat you can avoid casting and write:
`module.Name` instead of `((TypeLite.TsModels.TsModule)module).Name`

Comment: is there a way to remove all module declarations with formatter?  so that the final generated file is just interfaces and calss definitions.

Answer (score 3):

There is now an oveload of [`TypeScriptFluent.WithFormatter`](http://type.litesolutions.net/doc/TypeLite/TypeScriptFluent#WithFormatter) that takes `TsModuleNameFormatter` delegate, so that you can transform module names. For example this code converts module name to the last part of your namespace (`MyCompany.Business.Module1` -> `Module1`):

```
<#
var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
          .WithFormatter((TsModuleNameFormatter)FormatModuleName)
#>
<#+
string FormatModuleName(string module) {
    var parts = module.Split(new []{'.'});
    var newModule = parts[parts.Length - 1];
    return newModule;
}
#>
```

## Update:

In latest version of TypeLite **1.1.2.0** the API has changed slightly, so the previous example will look like this:

```
<#
var ts = TypeScript.Definitions().WithModuleNameFormatter((TsModuleNameFormatter)FormatModuleName)
#>
<#+
string FormatModuleName(TsModel module) {
    var parts = module.Name.Split(new []{'.'});
    var newName = parts[parts.Length - 1];
    return newName;
}
#>
```